# What would be the best way in which to regain performance from my machine

Tags: laptop, performance, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Optimization Tips for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/5859/best-optimization-tips-for-windows)

All,

my laptop is becoming increasingly slow so I am looking for ways to regain performance as it was on the last rebuild (I have to avoid rebuilding this time)

1. Currently I am using CCLeaner to
   remove all the OS generated temp
   files etc.
2. Moving everything
   unneeded of my hard disk
3. Defrag the
   disk after this is done

Is this enough will going through this tedious process actually make any real benefit? If not does any one have any guidance as to how to reclaim performance (the laptop is a reasonably respectable 2 years old Dell Latitude D830 2Ghz dual core, 2Gb RAM, 150 GB hard drive)

Comment: Related http://superuser.com/questions/5859/best-optimization-tips-for-windows

Comment: The things you listed above are good general guidance. To really tweak a machine for performance, it depends also on how you use it. Basically, removing everything not needed is the best way to go, be it things in your startup, tray icons, services, or old files taking up hard drive space. If you do memory intensive things, increasing the RAM helps. If you do CPU intensive things, stop unneeded processes (including Aero and eye candy), set the machine to best performance under performance options. If things are disk intensive, put the page file or data on a second disk. Performance is an art.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a defrag, clear-up the registry with CCLeaner (and rebooting afterwards) also deactivating cr** services starting at boot.

Best regards,